# I'm trying to build Ressurection Remix. When I run brunch, I get:*** missing separator and *** recipe commences before first target, for the same line

Tags: makefile

When i run brunch, i get these errors for the same line:

1) With tab

```
*** recipe commences before first target
```

2) Without tab

```
*** missing separator
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081364/makefile-errors-missing-separator-recipe-commences-before-first-tar) question already, but it didn't seem helpful.

The lines around the problematic line are:

```
# Wifi
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
dhcpcd.conf \
hostapd \
libwpa_client \
wpa_supplicant \
wpa_supplicant.conf \
lib_driver_cmd_mt66xx

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \    
librs_jni \
com.android.future.usb.accessory \
charger \
charger_res_images \
libnl_2 \
libion \
Snap
```

The line in qustion is

```
    librs_jni \
```

What am i doing wrong?

I have also attached my edited makefile [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jPZu8xXX9iHc2UqkK-3urcHSgyea-5S7)

(The problematic line is 41)

And the original makefile [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18KUUXtW6GNc993icbyQf76jK-azigPj8) (from the device tree on github)

Comment: Putting the code on an external site isn't really okay; your question should be self-contained.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly you have a tab before *every* line. That's not right; `make` wants a tab before every *recipe* line, which you actually seem to have none of (so you'll perhaps get an error for that then), while variable definitions most emphatically mustn't have one.

Comment: @tripleee The original makefile has no tabs, but with the original makefile, I get the ***missing separator error on that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` needs to be the last character in the line to act as the line-pasting token. You can't have white space after it.